# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Гибкие металлические шланги (,) в оплетке или без (,) для промышленного либо бытового применения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужны ли запятые?

Нужны.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119 :

> **§ 53.** Несогласованные определения, выраженные существительными в форме
> косвенных падежей с предлогами и
> относящиеся к нарицательным именам
> существительным, обособляются:
>
> 1) если определяемое слово уже имеет
> впереди стоящие согласованные
> определения...

Comment: Спасибо большое.